# Python Dictionary Object Conversion to JSON when Output Through Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, python-3.x, flask

I am using the Flask framework to obtain a dictionary object with the key set to the user ID and the value set to the username. From the view in Flask I am converting it to json using jason.dumps and when rendering the template, outputting direct to the Javascript code for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var = {{ users }};
   ...
</script>
```

When I examine the rendered HTML code the string value outputted looks as below, example given for one user:

```
var = {&#34;5d626ba11c9d4400004665b5&#34;: &#34;shears&#34;};
```

As you can see it is encoding the quote characters to their character value. How do I get this to output as a JSON object in the Javascript?

Comment: try `{{ users|safe }}` [Working with Automatic Escaping](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#working-with-automatic-escaping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could render a template variable inside a string, unescape HTML and then parse the result as JSON.

```
function unescapeHtml(safe) {
  return $('<div />').html(safe).text();
};

var usersDict = JSON.parse(unescapeHtml('{{ users }}'));
```

The usersDict variable is an object:

```
Object { 5d626ba11c9d4400004665b5: "shears" }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This object literal is not valid. The property name has to be in quotes, too.

Comment: @Thomas, the last line is just a copy-pasted output from a browser console, for demonstration purposes. The object is valid: one can get the "shears" value with usersDict["5d626ba11c9d4400004665b5"].

Comment: Many thanks, I've tested that and it seems to be working fine.